# Is there any idiom or expression that would imply " It is hard to argue against such rationale"?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Is there any idiom, expression or saying that would imply "this is a rational idea and there is no room to dispute, so one has no choice but to accept it" (i.e. "**It is hard to argue against such rationale"**)?

I have found "*[if the cap/ shoe fits، wear it"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/if-the-cap-fits-wear-it?q=If+the+shoe+fits%2C+wear+it%5C)*, but it seems that it can be used in situations when that discussing (rational) idea is an acceptable criticism, so I don't know if I can use it also for all other rationally acceptable ideas or not.

I want to use it in:

> James and Alex were arguing over a hot political issue, but after 50 minutes of continous discussion, James told Alex something which seemd so rational that Alex had no choice but to accept it, so Alex ended their discussion/ argument by saying:

"Okay, you're totally right, ___(= I can't argue with that, because it is rational and makes sense to me).

Comment: Is there something wrong with just saying it?  "I can't argue with that" is a fairly common phrase.

Comment: No, @HopelessN00b, Actually, I'm translating a context- story- from Persian into English, and a saying is used there that implies "rationales are indisputable"- by using it, the speaker announces that they have no reply to what the audience has said becuase it has been a rational and so indisputable idea- I just wanted to find a better translation for that part. :)

Comment: What is the literal translation of the Persian phrase? That might give us a feel for how idiomatic you're trying to be. I agree with others that "I can't argue with that" is the first phrase that springs to mind but it is maybe more literal and less "colourful" than you want?

Comment: @user2428107, It literally says "a rational/ reasonable statement has no reply".

Comment: That's actually quite literal! In that case maybe "I can't argue with that" is a good equivalent.

Comment: @user2428107, Yes! We use an idiomatic phrase for "rational statement" in Persian, but I don't know how to translate it in English. We use " a rational statement has no reply" with a mocking intonation if we have been the winner of the debate, ( it would imply :I see that you have no reply and just have to accept my rational idea!) and with a different intonation if we have been the loser! ( it would imply: I just give up! I have no choice but to accept your rational idea!) :)

Comment: "Well there it is", ["There you go"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48897/whats-the-meaning-of-there-you-go), " There you have it"...?

Comment: "Blown away by the unstoppable force of unassailable logic."  (As seen in [Abstruse Goose](http://abstrusegoose.com/537), which contains potentially NSFW language.)  ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All of these answers accurately describe how one would claim that their **own** argument has no room for dispute, but your question specifically mentions the speaker admitting the *other* side has a point. Therefore, I would suggest the following:

- "**I can't argue with that!**"
- "**You got me there.**"
- "**That's a good point.**"
- "**I'll give you that.**"

Inflection is important with all of these, and it might help to add "Well," or "I guess" to the start of each of them.

Comment: Maybe __touché__ as well? Although that brings other elements into it too.

Comment: Touche' moofre' (I made up the last word, is that allowed on a grammar site!? But it sounds funny as maybe a word taken from something Bart Simpson would say)

Answer (score 10):

I believe using the word "**touché**", where you are affirming someone else's rationale rather than your own, would be appropriate. If I'm understanding the scenario this would be what Alex would say in response to James' irrefutable argument.

Comment: Touché is rather for personal situations. Has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: "used as an acknowledgment during a discussion of a good or clever point made at one's expense by another person." In most civil arguments, there will never be points at someone's expense. This will rarely apply in OP's situation

Comment: I thought "touche" means nothing more than "you win"?

Answer (score 8):

*Case closed*

per http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/case+closed

> 1. Said after a given question, debate, or mystery has been solved or answered. *So you see, it was the dog who ate the blueberry pie, not
>      me. Case closed!*
> 2. The aforementioned decision, outcome, resolution, or situation is final, with no ambiguity or room for variation or amendment. *The only
>      way we'll be able to keep the company open is to undertake a 30%
>      reduction in staff, case closed. My wife had an affair and our
>      marriage is over. Case closed.*

This derives from its usage in legal proceedings and/or police investigations. A legal or police review is referred to as a case; when a perpetrator has been identified and/or convicted, that case is settled, or closed.

Comment: This is something said by one claiming victory, not one conceding defeat.

Answer (score 6):

**Q.E.D.**

Euclid's theorems state an aim, provide a logical argument and draw the intended conclusion. And then, in the latin version, add "Which is what ought to have been demonstrated" 
**Q.E.D.** Quod erat demonstrandum."

Comment: This is an appropriate closing comment by the person who presents the winning argument; it strikes me as unnatural for the "loser" to say.

Comment: This one doesn't make sense. 1) It's not an idiom. 2) It's field-specific. 3) It's generally written, not used in conversation. 4) It does fit the example given.

Answer (score 4):

You can talk about an "ironclad/irrefutable/undeniable argument"

> not able to be assailed or contradicted.

Comment: Also "indisputable".

Answer (score 4):

I always just say "fair enough".

When someone gives me a response that even though I may disagree with them it is something I can't really argue it just ends with "fair enough".

Answer (score 2):

Case closed is the best answer, **period**. But feel free to choose other alternatives like [period](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/period). It is

> used interjectionally to emphasize the finality of the preceding statement.

Example sentence - We are done - period.

With proper inflection, you can use it in any context.

Comment: "Absolutely no menstrual jokes will be tolerated.  **Period.**"

Comment: I think "period" is an American thing isn't it?  We don't say it over here in England.

Comment: It's still a good answer, full stop ;)

Answer (score 2):

A development that [spells your doom](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/spell-doom-for) is said to be **the last nail in the coffin**

> nail in the coffin of something also (a) nail in something's coffin.
>   An action that will cause something to end.   This report on the
>   effects of smoking is another nail in the coffin of the tobacco
>   industry. We thought the firings would put the final nail in the
>   union's coffin, but in fact, the union has grown in size and
>   importance.

nail in the coffin of. (n.d.) Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms. (2006). Retrieved May 12 2016 from http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/nail+in+the+coffin+of

The expression can be varied to suit the circumstance. If you said "well, I guess that seals the coffin", you are conceding the argument.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few of these:

- bulletproof
- ironclad
- logically sound
- unassailable
- unquestionable

All can be used as "A(n) [x] argument" or "Your argument is [x]."

Answer (score 1):

"Truth" or, "That is true." "No argument there."

Comment: I use these informal statements often when someone says something I agree with.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with [irrefutable logic.](http://dictionary.babylon-software.com/irrefutable_logic/)

> "I’ll follow the reedy tenor of his excuses and blast them with the
>   bellowy bass of irrefutable logic!" - Robert Sheckley
>
> "You're people, in short, who must be stupid, insane, or evil to
>   continue arguing in the face of indisputable facts and irrefutable
>   logic that others must be forced into a state of helplessness and
>   victimized by individual criminals or the state. Stupid, insane, or
>   evil." - L Neil Smith

Answer (score 1):

Well,

Using another possible colloquialism for this is the common usage of "***fuhgeddaboudit***".

In particular, from [The Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fuhgeddaboudit), I refer to definition 3 below:

> fuhgeddaboudit
>
> 1. Forget about it - the issue is not worth the time, energy, mental effort, or emotional resources.
> 2. Definitively "no."
> 3. The subject is unequivocally excellent; further thought and analysis are unnecessary.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

All answers so far seem to accept that the statement and facts are correct, it might be an appropriate response in an argument/discussion to say, " if what you say is true/correct then I cannot argue with that, however etc etc". I often find indisputable facts and irrefutable logic often need more scrutiny and sometimes viewing from a different perspective, when they then may be subject to different interpretations.

Answer (score 1):

I like **point taken**.

If you're in a formal/fantasy situation **I bow to your wisdom**/**the wisdom of your argument** also works.

Answer (score 1):

After going through my list of interesting words I've collected, these are the ones that seem most applicable:

**apodeictic**: Incontestable because of having been demonstrated

**apposite**: Suitable; fit; appropriate; applicable; well adapted: followed by to; (as in: "*This argument is very apposite to the case*")

**cogent**: Appealing to the mind or to reason; convincing.

**ratiocination**: The process of reasoning, or deducing conclusions from premises; deductive reasoning.

**perspicacity**: Clearness of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

"Now this is a true statement."
"I must give you that."
"That seems final/rational"
"I can't disagree"

Comment: Please explain why any of these might be appropriate.